# Is there a way to use the "Create Bug" from a run through the API

Tags: api, tfs

on a test result page in the UI 
(http:///DefaultCollection//_TestManagement/Runs?_a=resultSummary&runId=42&resultId=42) there is the "Create Bug" option under the bug carret; We are working on creating bugs from automated test failures when a test has had consistent failures for x days.

I have created bugs through the API but mine don't look as good as the ones generated through the "create bug" button. If there a way to piggyback on that functionality through the API? I'd love to get my hands on the formatted text under "Steps" and to get the links.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a bug with API which has the same text format under the **STEPS TO REPRODUCE** with the one created via "`Create Bug`" button?

Comment: I wanted to pass in my runId and resultId and get a work item Id back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a bug which has the same text format with the ones created by clicking "**Create Bug**" button, then you can get the bug details which created by **Create Bug** first, then copy the formatted text as the body to create new bugs.

1. Get the bug details which created by clicking "**Create Bug**"
   button, with REST API (See [Get a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-work-item)):

   ```
   GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/21
   ```

2-Copy the formatted text as the body to create new bug with REST API(See [Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item)):

```
PATCH http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/0323ScrumTFVC/_apis/wit/workitems/$Bug?api-version=3.0-preview

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "TestMethod1 Passed in 20180403.8-0410"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps",
    "value": "<span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">Test</span>: <b>UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1</b><br><span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">Priority</span>: <span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">not available</span><br><span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">Container</span>: unittestproject1.dll<br><span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">Machine</span>: VANLID242VM<br><span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">Tested build</span>: <a href=\"/tfs/DefaultCollection/0323ScrumTFVC/0323ScrumTFVC%20Team/_Build#_a=summary&amp;buildId=14\" target=_blank>20180403.8</a><br><span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">Error message</span>: <span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">not available</span><br><span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">Stack trace</span>: <span style=\"color:6d6d6d;\">not available</span><br><br>"
  }
]
```

Then you will see the same formatted text under "**Steps to reproduce**" with the links.

3- Then [Update test results for a test run](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#update-test-results-for-a-test-run) with the REST API

[image]

Comment: ok, let me see if this is going to work. I was hoping to be able to piggyback on the existing data formatting for stack trace etc. but I can do that legwork.

Comment: it is not what I wanted but it looks like it is as good as it is going to get.

it would be nice to expose the creation of test failures into a bug; but I can do the formatting manually.

Comment: @BasHamer Yeah, based on my test, we cannot use the “Create Bug” directly trough the API. The workaround I provided above is the most close way I can think of.